# Changing a cell with no dependents causes a full recalc of sheet that contains many formulas with UDF calls

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large spreadsheet in which several cells have formulas that call custom VBA functions in the spreadsheet.

Sometimes, *but not always*, if I alter an arbitrary cell that has no dependents at all (ie: no formulas in the spreadsheet reference the cell), it will cause a full recalculation of the workbook.

Is there any potentially logical explanation for this?

### Update

There is no code tied to SheetChange (no event handler exists), and no code behind any of the worksheets.

Comment: Yes there are several possibilities, but without more details we would just be guessing.

Comment: I'm not sure what further details I could provide?

Comment: Some examples of more details: how large is large, what is the calculation mode, what are the custom vba functions, what does the statusbar show, what excel version are you using, what addins are loaded, how many workbooks are open, how long does a recalculation take, how long does a full calculation take, is there any other vba code etc etc

Comment: @Charles - I'm not trying to be a jerk, but I'm not sure how any of those are relevant to my problem, unless an event handler can be added at runtime or something like that (something like that is what I'm thinking could conceivably cause it, but *I'm not aware of anything that is possible in Excel VBA* that could theoretically cause a recalc by changing a cell that has no dependents).

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if code is executed automatically from a *sheet* module upon change of defined (target) cells.

Comment: I checked this and no, there is no code reacting to the change of that cell.